# AntiSamy, Cannot find reference for java.io.CharArrayReader

Tags: c#, antisamy

I am trying to use AntiSamy at the first time.
I have added the source code of AntiSamy obtained from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project_.NET

But I can't build the project receive error:

```
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'java' could not be found 
            (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This function is using the library of "java":

```
java.io.CharArrayReader
```

Guys, where can i download this DLL?

Comment: Looks like it wants ikvm

Answer (score 0):

The Visual J# Runtime isn't deployed with the .NET Framework by default, you will need to install it

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4712

Note that J# is no longer shipped with newer versions of Visual Studio and that you are advised to replace your dependency on it with features from the .NET Framework or other supported 3rd party components.